# How to disable some radio buttons in SelectTable in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using `SelectTable` in react with `selectType='radio'`.

According to my case, some of the rows can be disabled depending on the condition. How to make those disabled?

I couldn't find anything on the official react-table page.

Comment: You can use onSelection function in your component, can you share some codes to get a better dig.

Comment: @Ankit I just have the basic code, where i use `<SelectTable />`. Just want to know if there are any props, or attributes i can pass on to the column elements, with which i can disable the selections.